# Installing Arch Linux on Thinkpad W530

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, system-installation, acpi

I am installing Arch Linux on a Thinkpad W530, using the LiveCD.
When I boot from the LiveCD, at the Syslinux bootloader screen, my hardware buttons (volume/mute) and Fn-keys work. I am able to control the brightness.
But once I boot into the **Arch live medium**, they stop working. I checked lsmod and have `thinkpad_acpi` running.
Is this just a problem because I am running LiveCD and haven't installed Arch yet?

Is there another module that I have to run? Do I need to install `Xorg` first?

I have installed Debian and Ubuntu, and almost everything works out of the box. Including when running their LiveCD. What allows Ubuntu to recognize the Fn-keys?

Comment: Does the W530 have optimus options in BIOS? Which GPU are you using to boot? Try adding `nox2apic` to the kernel boot line.

Comment: Yes, it does. I also tried just booting with the integrated card. And I added that parameter and I still get the same issue.

Comment: I feel like I had dealt with something like this before on Arch, can't remember specific fix.  What's the output of `lsmod`, if you can provide it somehow?

Comment: Wait, so the main question is about the **Function Keys** working correctly? Now I have to regroup my thoughts about this question.

Comment: Yes, sorry if I confused you. I was wondering why the Fn keys and hardware buttons work in the selection menu of the live CD but not the actual Arch live medium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `Fn` keys are mapped to X86... named keys. Therefore, I'm assuming you have to install the x-server first.  As for the brightness issue, [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight) has some relevant information, among which is the possible `systemd-backlight` problem/workaround:

> Inverted Brightness (Intel i915 only)
>
> Symptoms:
>
> after installing xf86-video-intel systemd-backlight.service turns off the backlight during boot
>
> possible solution: mask systemd-backlight.service
> switching from X to another VT turns the backlight off
> the brightness keys are inverted (i.e. turning up the brightness makes the screen darker)
>
> This problem may be solved by adding i915.invert_brightness=1 to the
> list of kernel parameters.

Comment: I installed `X` first. Still the same problem. I was hoping I could copy over some configuration files that Ubuntu uses, so I wouldn't have to bind the keys myself.